# Импорт из параллельной папки

Tags: python, python-3.x, импорт

Столкнулся с проблемой импортов.

Структура моего проекта

```
Dir
|--package
|  |--subpackage
|     |--file.py
|--package2
   |--file2.py
```

Мне нужно импортировать код из file.py в file2.py. Как это сделать? 
На маке работает просто `from package.subpackage.file import func`

На винде нет. Мне нужно чтобы работало и на маке и на винде.

UPD

```
F:\programs\python\python.exe F:/programs/projects/R-D/ParsingWeb/pars_teams.py
```

Знакомые говорят проблема в этом но я не знаю как решить. В терминале пайчарма указано 2 пути, раньше был 1 и все работало нормально. Говорят проблема с PATH, как ее решить?

UPD 
оказалась какая-то проблема с дублированием файлов, пересоздал файл и решилось само собой. Но способ ниже рабочий

Comment: https://qarchive.ru/15428_import_fai_lov_iz_raznyh_papok похожий вопрос

Comment: @Стас это за 2010 год, там еще питон 2, ссылки можно не кидать, я все облазил

Comment: @IceCube092, не нужно добавлять в заголовок вопроса solved, решено и т.д. Если вам помог ответ, вы можете отметить его как принятый (галка слева от ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import sys
import os

PACKAGE_PARENT = '..'
SCRIPT_DIR = os.path.dirname(
    os.path.realpath(os.path.join(os.getcwd(), os.path.expanduser(__file__)))
)
sys.path.append(os.path.normpath(os.path.join(SCRIPT_DIR, PACKAGE_PARENT)))

from package.subpackage.file import func


func()
```

Очень некрасивое решение, но должно работать в том числе на windows.

Comment: работает, но должен быть способ проще, я использую PyCharm, может в настройках чтото установить

Comment: попробуй в PyCharm нажать правой кнопкой мыши на директорию Dir, выбери "Mark Directory As", затем "Sources Root". Тогда должен начать корректно работать импорт `from package.subpackage.file import func`. Но надо понимать, что корректная работа будет только в рамках PyCharm.

Answer (score 2):

Согласно [документации по `sys.path`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.path):

> [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/sys.html#sys.path)
>
> ...
>
> As initialized upon program startup, the first item of this list,
> path[0], is the directory containing the script that was used to
> invoke the Python interpreter.
>
> ...

- при запуске интерпретатора в первый элемент списка `sys.path` попадает путь, где находится запускаемый файл (по вашей командной строке, это файл `pars_teams.py`, в `sys.path` будет добавлена директория `F:/programs/projects/R-D/ParsingWeb`). Поэтому интерпретатор автоматически будет видеть все пакеты, находящиеся в этой директории. Если "пусковой" файл находится внутри директории "Dir" на вашей схеме директорий, то все и так будет работать без дополнительных манипуляций.

Демонстрация:

```
C:\Users\user>tree Z:\Dir /f
Структура папок тома VBOX_Projects
Серийный номер тома: 0000-0801
Z:\DIR
│   pars_teams.py
│
├───package
│   └───subpackage
│           file.py
│
└───package2
        file2.py


C:\Users\user>python Z:\Dir\pars_teams.py
3.8.6 (tags/v3.8.6:db45529, Sep 23 2020, 15:52:53) [MSC v.1927 64 bit (AMD64)]
['Z:\\Dir', 'C:\\Python38\\python38.zip', 'C:\\Python38\\DLLs', 'C:\\Python38\\lib', 'C:\\Python38', 'C:\\Python38\\lib\\site-packages']
Z:\Dir\pars_teams.py
Z:\Dir\package\subpackage\file.py
Z:\Dir\package2\file2.py
```

Содержимое файлов:

- `pars_teams.py`:

  ```
  import sys
  print(sys.version)
  print(sys.path)
  print(__file__)

  import package.subpackage.file
  ```
- `package\subpackage\file.py`:

  ```
  print(__file__)

  import package2.file2
  ```
- `package2\file2.py`:

  ```
  print(__file__)
  ```

[image: Скриншот]