# Импорт из параллельных папок

Tags: python, импорт

Есть структура проекта:

```
Project
|--general_project_files.py
|--folder1
   |--additional_files1.py
|--folder2
   |--additional_files2.py
```

**Что нужно:** 
Нужно импортировать additional_files1.py в additional_files2.py или наоборот, неважно.

Я пытался писать:
`from ..folder1 import additional_files1`,
`from .folder1 import additional_files1`,
`from folder1.additional_files1 import function`
Пробовал создавать файлы **init** в каждом каталоге при этих импортах, но всегда пишет ошибку. Либо при исполнении функции пишет что данного модуля (импортированного) не найдено, либо сразу при запсуке `ImportError: attempted relative import with no known parent package`.
Наткнулся на этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1124232/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D0%B8), но мне не нравится такой кастыль. Уж лучше все файлы скидать в одну кучу. Подскажите, может есть какой нибудь хороший, 'ровный' способ сделать импорт из паралельных папок чтобы всё было цивильно?
Извиняюсь если вопрос глупый, но информации которая бы меня удовлетворяла не нашёл.

Comment: Мне кажется или по нормальному это нельзя сделать

Comment: Если запускать проект как пакет (с ключом -m) из внешней директории (например, `python -m Project.general_project_files`), тогда будет работать относительный импорт. Указывать расширение в названиях модуля при импорте не нужно, так точно не будет работать. Ну и если additional_files1.py будет импортировать additional_files2.py, а additional_files2.py импортировать additional_files1.py, то получится циклический импорт, так работать не будет.

Comment: блин, ошибся в написании примера. Писал без расширений.

Comment: @PandaStock как-то так: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAJMP.png

Comment: С таким способом запуска импорт some_project.folder1, some_project.folder2 тоже будет работать: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lElJU.png

Comment: пишет что импорт не может быть разрешён. Но у меня отличие в том что выше папки нет. То есть без some_project

Comment: В попытках следовать примерам изменил название родительского каталога и перезапуске IDe вышел из вирт.среды. Попробовал в additional_files1.py записать ```from folder2 import additional_files2.py``` и при запуске всё запустилось и выдало тестовый принт. Ничего не понимаю, почему то в вирт.среде при такой попытке импорта писало ошибку о ненайденом модуле.

Comment: @PandaStock в моем примере я создал пакет some_project, и запускал его из директории Project. Со структурой каталогов как в вопросе нужно выйти на уровень выше, и оттуда запускать. Если через `from folder2 import additional_files2` заработало, то возможно у вас PyCharm и он сам добавил директорию, отмеченную как Sources, в PYTHONPATH, по сути то же самое, что в ответе по ссылке, которую вы привели в вопросе.

Comment: Нет, VSCode. Но что то мне подсказывает что при большом количестве попыток ранее, я допустил синтаксическую ошибку в "правильном" импортировании, потому способ я забраковал и пошёл ухищрятся дальше. Странно, то что информацию на разных форумах сводится к sys и импортированию через него.

Comment: @PandaStock, чтобы понять почему заработало, нужно смотреть как в итоге заработало (структура каталогов, содержимое файлов, как запускаете, откуда запускаете). Никакой магии тут нет.

Comment: меня до сих по смущает как питон увидел паралельную папку проекта. Ведь по сути, мы можем спускаться по импорту глубже или выше через ```.. from```.

Comment: Ну в общем у меня тоже через `from folder2 import additional_files2` и простым запуском general_project_files.py через `python3 general_project_files.py` тоже заработало. Возможно вы запускали как-то не так. "Ведь по сути, мы можем спускаться по импорту глубже или выше через .. from." - относительный импорт работает только внутри пакета. В примере в вопросе у вас folder1 и folder2 - пакеты, нельзя через относительный импорт "выйти" из одного пакета и "зайти" в другой. Но абсолютный импорт по имени пакета работает, похоже.

Comment: @insolor благодарю за помощь!

Comment: Я в общем добавил ответ под тем вопросом, все оказалось проще, чем я думал: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1372719/1365